# mysql select stock minus sold from multiple rows if contains stock

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables article and batches.
What a want is to retrieve only the batch numbers (quantity-sold) when someone buys stock.
The stock quantity is stored in batches because of the production date FIFO.

```
article 

id|number|name
------------------
5|14432|Chemical H01
6|14433|Chemical H33
7|14434|Chemical HA1/5


batches

id|article_id|stock|batch_number|production_date
------------------
1|5|100|#34456|2021-09-21
2|5|21|#34476|2021-09-22
3|5|200|#34470|2021-10-11
4|5|100|#34471|2021-10-10
5|6|501|#77633|2021-10-11
6|6|100|#77634|2021-12-20
7|9|755|#90223|2021-12-30
```

If someone wants to buy 110 stock from article (id) 5 I want to retrieve 2 batch numbers; 1,2. (starting from oldest production_date)

If someone wants to buy 200 stock from article (id) 5 I want to retrieve 3 batch numbers; 1,2,4.  (starting from oldest production_date)

```
SELECT a.number, ( 
                   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(batch_number SEPARATOR ', ') 
                   FROM batches 
                   WHERE article_id=a.id
                 ) AS batch_number 
FROM article AS a 
WHERE a.id=5
```

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: What's your mysql version

Comment: development: mysql 5.7.31 production: MariaDB 5.5.68

Comment: Ok I see I write answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your MySQL version supports the window function, you can try to use `SUM` window function to get the accumulation from `stock` each `article_id` which can compare from your logic buy stock, then use

**Query #1**

```
SELECT t2.number,
       GROUP_CONCAT(batch_number SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM (
     SELECT *,SUM(stock) OVER(PARTITION BY article_id ORDER BY production_date) accumulation
     FROM batches
) t1 INNER JOIN article t2
ON t1.article_id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id = 5 AND (accumulation - stock) < 200  --buy stock 
GROUP BY t2.number;
```

| number | GROUP_CONCAT(batch_number SEPARATOR ', ') |
| --- | --- |
| 14432 | #34456, #34476, #34471 |

---

If your MySQL version didn't support there is another way to do that.

using correlated-subquery get accumulation in a subquery then filter accumulation as your logic.

```
SELECT t2.number,
       GROUP_CONCAT(batch_number SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM (
    SELECT *,
           (SELECT SUM(bb.stock) FROM batches bb WHERE bb.article_id = b.article_id AND bb.production_date < b.production_date) accumulation
    FROM batches b
) t1 INNER JOIN article t2
ON t1.article_id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id = 5 AND coalesce(accumulation,0) < 200  --buy stock 
GROUP BY t2.number;
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7JXyAd3KUNdWpywTi8oDsY/2)

Comment: You're a legend!